# Starting Jboss server 5.x at 8843 port

Tags: java, jboss, jboss5.x

Following command is starting jboss server 5.x at port-8743

```
sh run.sh -b $ipaddress  -Djboss.service.binding.set="ports-03"  >> nohup.out &
```

But port 8743 is occupied by other jboss server instance, so i want to start jboss to 8843 port. To do this i invoked following command

```
sh run.sh -b $ipaddress  -Djboss.service.binding.set="ports-04"  >> nohup.out &
```

but got error

```
14:20:39,191 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Instantiated: name=SystemPropertyBinder#2 state=Described
org.jboss.services.binding.NoSuchBindingException: No binding netty-port found for service JBM2 in set ports-04
    at org.jboss.services.binding.impl.PojoServiceBindingStore.getServiceBinding(PojoServiceBindingStore.java:98)
    at org.jboss.services.binding.ServiceBindingManager.getIntBinding(ServiceBindingManager.java:217)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:59)
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:150)
    at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66)
    at org.jboss.beans.info.plugins.AbstractBeanInfo.invoke(AbstractBeanInfo.java:300)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelControllerContext.invoke(AbstractKernelControllerContext.java:286)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dispatch.InvokeDispatchHelper.invoke(InvokeDispatchHelper.java:104)
    at org.jboss.beans.metadata.plugins.AbstractValueFactoryMetaData.getValue(AbstractValueFactoryMetaData.java:332)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.config.Configurator.getParameters(Configurator.java:629)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.config.Configurator.getConstructorJoinPoint(Configurator.java:206)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.config.AbstractKernelConfigurator.getConstructorJoinPoint(AbstractKernelConfigurator.java:137)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstantiateAction.installActionInternal(InstantiateAction.java:61)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.jmx.ServiceControllerStartStopLifecycleCallback.install(ServiceControllerStartStopLifecycleCallback.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:59)
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:150)
    at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66)
    at org.jboss.beans.info.plugins.AbstractBeanInfo.invoke(AbstractBeanInfo.java:300)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelControllerContext.invoke(AbstractKernelControllerContext.java:286)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractLifecycleCallbackItem.install(AbstractLifecycleCallbackItem.java:87)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.handleLifecycleCallbacks(AbstractController.java:1568)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.handleInstallLifecycleCallbacks(AbstractController.java:1533)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:943)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:774)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:540)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:121)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:51)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
 14:20:39,194 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Instantiated: name=SystemPropertyBinder#1 state=Described
org.jboss.services.binding.NoSuchBindingException: No binding null found for service jboss.messaging:service=Connector,transport=bisocket in set ports-04
    at org.jboss.services.binding.impl.PojoServiceBindingStore.getServiceBinding(PojoServiceBindingStore.java:98)
    at org.jboss.services.binding.ServiceBindingManager.getIntBinding(ServiceBindingManager.java:217)
    at org.jboss.services.binding.ServiceBindingManager.getIntBinding(ServiceBindingManager.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

what will be command for starting jboss 5.x at 8843 port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your server/default/conf/bindingservice.beans/META-INF/bindings-jboss-beans.xml (default or whatever instance being used) and add the following:

```
<!-- The ports-04 bindings are obtained by taking ports-default and adding 400 to each port value -->
   <bean name="Ports04Bindings" class="org.jboss.services.binding.impl.ServiceBindingSet">
      <constructor>
         <!--  The name of the set -->
         <parameter>ports-04</parameter>
         <!-- Default host name -->
         <parameter>${jboss.bind.address}</parameter>
         <!-- The port offset -->
         <parameter>400</parameter>
         <!-- Set of bindings to which the "offset by X" approach can't be applied -->
         <parameter><null/></parameter>
      </constructor>
   </bean>
```

This configuration adds 400 to the default ports, so 8443 becomes 8843

EDIT: As @user752590 said, it's also necessary to add the following:

```
<!--  The binding sets -->
 <parameter>
    <set>
       <inject bean="PortsDefaultBindings"/>
       <inject bean="Ports01Bindings"/>
       ..
       ..
       <inject bean="Ports04Bindings"/>
    </set>
 </parameter>
```

Comment: Following line has also been added in above configuration file ------>  <inject bean="Ports04Bindings"/>